# Lunching Spyder gives Bad address, completely fresh environment

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I cant get spyder to run.
I do conda create -n somename python=3.8.5 spyder=4
Or alternatively python=3.7.5 and spyder without version numbers.
I have also tried the simple way and create a new environemtn via anaconda navigator.

In all cases, I get the below error as aoson as i run spyder.
I do have other environments on my pc and they rund fine.
What could be going on here?

Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[7432:1424:1219/110906.333:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)
[20456:7284:1219/110906.333:ERROR:broker_win.cc(59)] Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you using a VPN? Or perhaps a restrictive antivirus/firewall? Please deactivate them and try again.